# Button Visibility Inside DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I'm fairly new to WPF and MVVM, and have run into a problem. I have a DataGrid that gets populated when a member is added to the system. I have a button that allows the user to log in - I need to hide this button by default and only appear once a member is added. I've been reading up on how the relative source works but to be completely honest I'm a little confused, any help would be very welcome.

ViewModel

```
 private bool _showButton;

    public bool ShowButton
    {
        get { return _showButton; }
        set
        {
            _showButton = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ShowButton");
        }
    }
```

View

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedPerson}"
                  Margin="0,23,0,0" Width="500" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
               <DataGridTextColumn Header="Full Name" Binding="{Binding FullName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Email" Binding="{Binding Email}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Binding="{Binding AddressLine1}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Contact" Binding="{Binding ContactNumber}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <mui:ModernButton Command="{Binding Path= DataContext.NavigateToItemViewCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" 
                                              Visibility="{Binding ShowButton,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter},FallbackValue=Hidden}"   
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding}">Log User</mui:ModernButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit----How I'm updating ShowButton prop. After adding a person to a Observable Collection, I set the ShowButton bool to true.

```
Person person = personRepo.Get(member.PersonId);
var tmp = AddPersons(person);
foreach (var item in tmp)
{
   Persons.Add(item);
}
 ShowButton = true;
```

EDIT - Fixed - Added the showbutton property to my person model and working as expected.

```
Person person = personRepo.Get(member.PersonId);
var tmp = AddPersons(person);
foreach (var item in tmp)
{
 Persons.Add(item);
 item.ShowButton = true;
};
```

Comment: Is `ShowButton` in the same class as `AddressLine1` and `ContactNumber`?

Comment: Yes, Address Line 1 and Contact Number are in the same ViewModel as ShowButton

Comment: Your code and markup seems fine at first glance, what exactly is not working?

Comment: @bucky112 so what is not working? You're setting/initializing `ShowButton` to false and it's making button invisible? Other columns display fine?

Comment: After adding a member  to the datagrid I set the ShowButton bool value to True, this does nothing and the button is still hidden.

Comment: Can you show how you change `ShowButton` and also I know you do `RaisePropertyChanged` but does your view model actually implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: I've updated my original post,  and if I try and inherit INotifyPropertyChanged I get: Base interface is redundant because ViewModel inherits ViewModelBase

Comment: So it is not in the same class as `AddressLine1` and `ContactNumber ` otherwise I would expect `item.ShowButton = true` in the loop. You can make it work but, as it is, changing `ShowButton` will work for all items in the list not for newly added items

Comment: ShowButton is  defined in the same ViewModel as AddreessLine1 and ContactNumber, but itns't apart of person. The strange thing is the logic works fine for another button I have, it's just not working for the one inside the datagrid. I'll try what you said and add the showButton into the loop. Edit - Doesn't seem to make any difference the button won't change visibility.

Comment: You lost me here. I don't understand how it can be part of same view model but not be a part of `Person`. You add items to `Persons` list which, I guess, is the same list bound to `DataGrid` where each item should have `FullName`, `Email`, `AddressLine1`, `ContactNumber` and `ShowButton` properties yet you add `item` to `Persons` but set `ShowButton` in the same object that manages `Persons` and not against `item` (each person).

Comment: You can do it either way but if you want to do it per `Person` then `ShowButton` should be part of each item or if for all items (not just newly added) then you need to use `RelativeSource`

Comment: Thank you, I added the ShowButton property to the person model and it works now.